# Mapping an amazon server to a domain name registered with name.com

Tags: dns, amazon

I have an amazon S3 web server and a domain name registered in name.com (the name is sam-experiments.com). I am trying to have a static page hosted on the amazon web server to be displayed on http://www.sam-experiments.com

On the web server side, my bucket name is 'www.sam-experiments.com', and it links to here: http://www.sam-experiments.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

On name.com, I added a new record with the followin characteristics:

- Record Type: CNAME
- Record Host: www.sam-experiments.com
- Record Answer: www.sam-experiments.com.s3.amazonaws.com. (as specified in the documentation here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs)
- TTL: 300

However, nothing gets displayed on www.sam-experiments.com, and I am not able to find what I am doing wrong.

I really would appreciate some tip.
Thanks!

Note: I already posted this question in stackoverflow, but didnt get any answer, so I thought posting here may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to map my website to my server. I will quikcly explain how, maybe it will be useful for someone who has the same problem.

I just went to "URL forwarding" on name.com and put my amazon link: http://www.sam-experiments.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

For some reason, I have control of http://sam-experiments.com but not http://sam-experiments.com, which confused me for a while...

Answer (score 2):

In the Amazon configuration for your web server, are you able to tell Amazon that the name of your web server is `www.sam-experiments.com`?  You need to be able to do that somehow so that when Amazon receives an HTTP request with `Host: www.sam-experiments.com` in it, it knows what to do with it.

This is very similar to how Akamai works.  Akamai also uses DNS CNAMES just as you have described.  However, in the Akamai configuration for the web site you have to tell Akamai the name of the digital property which is the host name that you are using for the web site.

From the Amazon documentation you referenced:

> Create a bucket that matches the host name.
>
> In this example, the host and bucket names are images.johnsmith.net.
>
> Note
>
> Your bucket name must exactly match the host name.

Does your bucket name in Amazon exactly match the host name?

Is your bucket name all lower case as they recommend?  See the limitations note from the documentation shown below.

> **Limitations**
>
> Because DNS names are case insensitive, only lower-case buckets are
>   addressable using the virtual hosting method. For more information,
>   see Bucket Restrictions and Limitations.

Also, looking at the documentation in more detail, why did you use www.sam-experiments.com.s3.amazonaws.com instead of www.sam-experiments.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com in the CNAME?

Going to just http://www.sam-experiments.com.s3.amazonaws.com returns:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>1A02939C75C5CDC8</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        3XAYwSXkWhkvXFG4gNyCYyBpb9g2kMv1L4Zv9UJCSX/L21peb19KbaSMhfqb/hrW
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. To answer your questions: 

 1) I am not able to tell amazon that the name of my web server www.sam-experiments.com

 2) my bucket name is "www.sam-experiments.com", which does (I think) match exactly the host name

 3) using in the CNAME www.sam-experiments.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com doesnt work either.


My thought was that I using a CNAME enables me to tell name.com something like "go to this record answer, take the content and redirect it to the domain name". Is this correct or do I need to tell amazon about my domain name as well?

Answer (score 0):

URL forwording will cause more problems like sending post requests from your website, sot to link your dns with your S3 bucket follow these steps:

1. go to your S3 bucket > properties > static website hosting and copy the url.
2. in your name.com account go to manage DNS records and create a new record.
3. Select type ANAME since CNAME is not recomended in name.com.
4. paste the S3 link in answer and delete the http:/ part.
5. save your work, your website will be available in a while.